How to remove empty areas from screenshots generated from Autodesk Viewer?
I would like to remove empty areas from screenshots generated from Autodesk Viewer. See the below picture. I'm using Autodesk Platform Services API and Autodesk Viewer.
enter image description here
Any help?
To take screenshots, I'm　using "Autodesk.Viewing.ScreenShot.getScreenShot" method.

have you tried crop function from this blog? https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/more-screenshots
